# how to store CSV data into mongoDB using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, csv

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });
const csv = require('csvtojson');

public fileUpload = async  (req, res): Promise<any> => {
const fileBuffer = req.files[0].buffer.toString();
res.status(200).json({ fileBuffer });
csv({
  noheader:true,
  output: 'csv',
}).fromString(fileBuffer)
    .then((csvRow) => {
      csvRow.shift();
      this.create(req , res, csvRow);
    });
}
```

> > //above lines are my code i am getting data in below format i want to 
> >         store this data in mongoDB

```
>[
> [Deepak ,4434444554,454466656,Tata],
> [Naren,8837377373,343443434,Tata]
>]
```

> > //this is my create method here i want to match data with schema and store it into database

```
 public create (req, res, object) {
console.log('hi-----------', object);
const { partner_name, mobile_no, alternate_no, vehicle_type } = 
object;
try {
  const lead = new leadModels({
    alternate_no, mobile_no, partner_name, vehicle_type,
  });
  const newLead = lead.save();
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'lead created successfully' });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).json({ message: appData.internalServerError });
}
```

}

Comment: Just an idea - using the [From CSV file to JSON array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#from-csv-file-to-json-array) _option_ returns an array of JSON with key-value pairs. This might be easy to insert into the collection.